# I am working on a VBA project with selenium and I am wondering how to find an element if the class names are the same

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to get the second or third of the classes shown, '4' now but will change, but the class names are the same. How can I get the class I want and send it to a cell on the file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To find individual `ts` class.

```
(//span[@class='Dj']//span[@class='ts'])[1]
(//span[@class='Dj']//span[@class='ts'])[2]
(//span[@class='Dj']//span[@class='ts'])[3]
```

You can also try directly, if it works:

To find individual ts class

```
(//span[@class='ts'])[1]
(//span[@class='ts'])[2]
(//span[@class='ts'])[3]
```